# Using \uncover inside a TikZ node text

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, overlays

I am unable to use `\uncover` inside the text of a TikZ node. Here is what I would like to do:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
            \node[align=center] (a) {test 1 \\ \uncover<2>{test 12345}};
            \node[align=center,right of=a] (b) {test 2};
            \path[->] (a) edge (b);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This gives: "! Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?."

Using `\onslide` gives the same result. Using `\only` does work, but because my second line is longer, the node is enlarged and everything else shifts.

I'd be curious to understand why `\only` works but not `\uncover` or `\onslide`, but mostly, I would like to know if there is a simple way (e.g. simpler than having a `minipage` inside the node text) to prevent the node from changing size.

Comment: Create the node twice. Once only for slide 1. Once only for slide 2. Then use `\phantom` for the relevant part of the first slide. ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need another set of braces:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
            \node[align=center] (a) {test 1 \\ {\uncover<2>{test 12345}}};  %wrapped \uncover into {}
            \node[align=center,right of=a] (b) {test 2};
            \path[->] (a) edge (b);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
          \onslide<1>{%
            \node[align=center] (a) {test 1 \\ \phantom{test 12345}};}
          \onslide<2->{%
            \node[align=center] (a) {test 1 \\ test 12345};}
            \node[align=center,right of=a] (b) {test 2};
            \path[->] (a) edge (b);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: phantom text...]