# Beamer, tikz-cd: uncover does not work

Tags: beamer, overlays, tikz-cd

I have a similar problem to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/204499/7548), only I'm using `tikz-cd` instead of `tikz`.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
1{\uncover<2->{\arrow{r}}}\&2
\end{tikzcd}
\end{frame}
```

This will have two slides, both having the arrow. Removing the `{...}` will lead to an Error:

```
Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?
```

Using `\only` instead of `\uncover` does work, but does move things in bigger diagrams, which I don't want.

Is there a workaround without converting all my `tikz-cd` diagrams into `tikzpicture`s?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the `visible on` style:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\tikzset{
    invisible/.style={opacity=0},
    visible on/.style={alt={#1{}{invisible}}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
      \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}}%
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
1 \arrow[visible on=<2->,r]\arrow[visible on=<3>,d] \& 2\arrow[visible on=<2->,d] \\
3 \arrow[visible on=<3>,r] \& 4 
\end{tikzcd}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can you apply this visibility to the nodes? That is, to make them appear together with each relevant arrow?

Comment: I found the answer to my question: you can pass key-value pairs to nodes using the syntax `|[key=value]|` before the node. Thus, node 3 can be shown from slide three onwards with `|[visible on=<3->]| 3`.

Comment: @Tom-Verhoeff, I can't believe that works! Thanks for answering your own question publicly.